# FFTW 2.1.5 not working on cygwin

Tags: windows, cygwin, configure, fftw

I am trying to install fftw using cygwin on my windows machine. However, when calling the configure file an issue occurs. I need fftw to have full mpi support, so I am doing the command:

```
./configure --enable-mpi --enable-type-prefix --enable-float
```

which results in the error:

```
-bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
```

However, when calling only the ./configure, the config file runs without issue.
The `./configure --enable-mpi --enable-type-prefix --enable-float` call worked with no issue in ubuntu, but is now giving me issues in cygwin. What could possibly be the issue with the extra text in cygwin?

Comment: it works for me, after copying `/usr/share/automake-1.7/config.guess` in the source tree. Have you installed the openmpi header ?

Comment: Additional question, more a curiosity:  why 2.1.5 ? Latest is 3.3.4